# unable Login to iSQL as SYS or SYSDBA

Tags: sql, oracle

I installed oracle 9i on my Win XP 32bit, while installing I checked users as HR, SYS and SYSDBA and passwords as HR, SYS and SYSDBA respectively. I can login to isql*plus as HR but not as SYS and SYSDBA. Also what should be the connection identifier for SYS and SYSDBA.
Assuming that the password is wrong (which i know is not), I tried to search for the password change utility, but i found nothing in the ALL PROGRAMS MENU. I need access as a SYSDBA or SYS in order to study further. I was actually trying to use the Tables.txt file that comes with Oracle 9i Complete Reference book in order to create the same tables as given in the book, but it keeps throwing an error "insufficient privileges" whenever i try to run that script. I use HR privileges to do so.

Please help.

Comment: Well, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: SYSDBA is a role, not a user. How are you connecting, exactly? (And why are you installing such an old version anyway?)

Comment: I put SYS(username), SYS(pwd) and nothing in Connection Identifier and choose SYSDBA then I get a pop up. CONNECT TO iSQL*PLUS, then i put SYS as username and SYS as password and the same pop-up comes back. It doesn't go further.

Comment: right sysdba is a role, i use SYS as username and password. i am little comfortable using 9i because i had earlier studies it some time ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Plus when prompted for Username , enter

```
SYS as SYSDBA
```

SYS is user and SYSDBA is role you want to log with

Comment: not sql plus, iSQL*plus. 
right sysdba is a role, i use SYS as username and password.  
I put SYS(username), SYS(pwd) and nothing in Connection Identifier and choose SYSDBA then I get a pop up. CONNECT TO iSQL*PLUS, then i put SYS as username and SYS as password and the same pop-up comes back. It doesn't go further.

Comment: ok i misread it, however in each db client it has to be possible to provide role under which you want to log in, so there should be possible to enter  "SYS as SYSDBA"

Comment: did you try CONNECT TO SYS/paswd as SYSDBA ?

Comment: sorry for such a delayed reply.. yes i tried that but unable to login. what should be in connection identifier? and is there any way to check or reset the password?